# Grab the ID of a SPAN tag and add some value to a Text Box Field according to which tag has been clicked

Tags: jquery

I was trying to grab the ID of the SPAN tag when a user clicked it.
Since the ID of each tag contains two digits, they would be used for referring
to the value of their corresponding hidden text box field,
but I am stuck over this question.

Here is part of the code that I have written.
I need your help to finish it because I don't know how to move on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $("#^=content").click(function(event){
        // var digit = extract the last two digit of the id
           var id_of_the_hidden_field = "hidden"+digit;
           $("#show").val()=$("#hidden").val();
            });
        });
</script>
<div id="test22">
<span id="content22">Click to add the value</span>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden22" value="hello">
</div>

<div id="test33">
<span id="content33">Click to add the value</span>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden33" value="world">
</div>

<input type="text" id="show">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
$("[id^=content]").click(function(event){
  $("#show").val($("#" +   this.id.replace('content', 'hidden')).val());
});​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TCvq/).  There are a few corrections to this, first you need an [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) ([`[attr^=value]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)) to find the elements by ID (though you could give the spans a class and use `.class` as well).  Then we're using the ID, replacing `'content'` with `'hidden'` via [`string.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) and grabbing input element by that ID.  Also when setting a value use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), `.val() = value` isn't valid :)

If the structure is consistent you can make this much simpler, by relying on the fact that the `<input type="hidden" />` is beside the `<span>` like this:

```
$("[id^=content]").click(function(event){
    $("#show").val($(this).next().val());
});​
```

[You cant test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TCvq/1/)

---

As I said in the first example, if adding classed in an option it will makes your life easier, here's a version doing that:

```
<div id="test22">
  <span id="content22" class="clickable">Click to add the value</span>
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden22" value="hello">
</div>    
<div id="test33">
  <span id="content33" class="clickable">Click to add the value</span>
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden33" value="world">
</div>    
<input type="text" id="show">​​​​​​
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(event){
  $("#show").val($(this).next().val());
});​
```

[Here's that version in a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TCvq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("[id^=content]").click(function(event){
        var digit = this.id.replace("content","");
        $("#show").val($("#hidden" + digit).val());
    });
});
</script>
<div id="test22">
<span id="content22">Click to add the value</span>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden22" value="hello">
</div>

<div id="test33">
<span id="content33">Click to add the value</span>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden33" value="world">
</div>

<input type="text" id="show">
```

Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vNAEd/

Comment: Thank you for the help, digitalFresh.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
 var digit = $(this).attr(id).substring(7, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

your selector is wrong. Use `$("span[id^=content]")` instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
           $("span[id^=content]").click(function(event){
           var id = this.id;
           var digit = id.substring(id.length -2 , id.length);
           var id_of_the_hidden_field = "#hidden"+digit;
           $("#show").val( $( id_of_the_hidden_field  ).val() );
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will work for you:

```
$("[id^=content]").click(function(){
  $("#show").val($("#hidden"+this.id.substr(-2)).val());
});
```

Here's [the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/8xwxC/).