# USe JQUery Next() API to grab the data from a hidden Text Box

Tags: jquery

I am doing some self-learning about JQuery and stuck over a question:
I am trying to use the JQuery next() API to grab the data from the Text Box field of Hidden type, but I failed to do so.
Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Testing").click(function(){
    var what =  $(this).next().val();
    alert(what);
    });
 });

<span class="Testing">Hello</span><br/>
<input type="hidden" value="World">

 <span class="Testing">Hi</span><br/>
 <input type="hidden" value="There">
```

Could you help me solve the question please?

Reference link:
[Grab the ID of a SPAN tag and add some value to a Text Box Field according to which tag has been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223446/grab-the-id-of-a-span-tag-and-add-some-value-to-a-text-box-field-according-to-whi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to close the call to $(document).ready.
It needs extra });

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Testing").click(function(){
        var what =  $(this).next().val();
        alert(what);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="Testing">Hello</span>
<input type="hidden" value="World">

<span class="Testing">Hi</span>
<input type="hidden" value="There">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

.next() is for jquery Objects that contain a set of dom objects.

you'd use it for things like lists.   check out the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/next/

actually you should be able to do what your trying.  ignore this.